# Rviz is not loading

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running commands for Rviz I am not getting any output on the terminal and Rviz gui is not loading. I am running Indigo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266957/rviz-is-not-loading/) by [tyberious](https://answers.ros.org/users/28909/tyberious/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-20**:
Are you running `roscore`?

**Comment by [tyberious](https://answers.ros.org/users/28909/tyberious/) on 2017-07-20**:
I am running roscore.

**Comment by [tyberious](https://answers.ros.org/users/28909/tyberious/) on 2017-07-20**:
:~$ rosrun rviz rviz

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-20**:
Run `rosrun rqt_logger_level rqt_logger_level` and play around with the different loggers and logger levels for `rviz` and see if that tells you anything.

**Comment by [tyberious](https://answers.ros.org/users/28909/tyberious/) on 2017-07-20**:
Hey Jayess I am not seeing rviz listed when running  `rosrun rqt_logger_level rqt_logger_level`

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-20**:
The node name should be something along the lines of `/rviz_1500579339612988311`.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-20**:
How did you install `ROS`?

**Comment by [tyberious](https://answers.ros.org/users/28909/tyberious/) on 2017-07-20**:
`sudo apt install ros-indigo-desktop-full`  I dont have anything that looks like that  `/rviz_1500579339612988311`

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-20**:
And nothing gets output to the terminal when you run `rosrun rviz rviz`?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-21**:
As with all RViz questions: please tell us whether you're running Linux/ROS in a VM, which OS this is, whether you have drivers installed for your 3D hardware, etc, etc.

Please *update* your original question. Comments are not meant for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If running apt install is all you did to install ROS and you haven't setup your environment things won't likely work right. Have you followed the [installation tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu)?

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2017-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0